# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in taxonomy.php on line 3442 and category-template.php on line 1279

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I am getting these 2 PHP notices in my Wordpress loop, I have researched all over but I can't figure out how to fix the issue. The script works as intended but the notices appear all over the page.

Notice: Array to string conversion in \wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 3442

Notice: Array to string conversion in \wp-includes\category-template.php on line 1279

I have searched the internet and I think this might be the code that is causing the issue but I can't figure out what is breaking it and no matter what I try I seem unable to fix it. Please could someone help me fix this and explain the issue to me.

```
     <?php

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
$i=1;
            // Start the Loop 
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
          ?>
                <?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, array('date-category', 'programme-category') );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

    $catTag = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $catTag[] = $term->slug;
    }

    $catTag = implode(" ", $catTag );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - **$post** *(int|[WP_Post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/)) (Required)* Post ID or object.
> - **$taxonomy** *(string) (Required)* Taxonomy name.

[get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) expects the second parameter, `$taxonomy`, to be a **string**, yet you're passing an **array**:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, array('date-category', 'programme-category') );
```

That's why you're seeing that "Array to string conversion" error message.

You can only pass a single taxonomy to the function, not two as you're doing there. For example:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'date-category' );
```

or:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'programme-category' );
```

Comment: Not to pass an array as the second parameter to the `get_the_terms()` function @klewis. You should pass a string (the taxonomy name, eg. 'books') instead.

Comment: It's explained above. I even shared two examples...

Comment: That's the point, you cannot pass an array as the second parameter. The function only accepts an string as the second parameter (as explained above), see [get_the_terms() parameters documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/#parameters). Passing an array will trigger the PHP notice as reported by OP.

Comment: If he can't use get_the_terms(), then tell him what he can use.